# Stable/Unstable Manifold heorem

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems

Why does the stable/unstable manifold theorem imply that the power series expansion of the stable/unstable manifold is locally convergent? (local to the fixed point)
[image]

Comment: Hm. I think it's necessary here to put a reference to the theorem that you mean. If power series are convergent then (un)stable manifold is analytic, so it's a sort of special case.

Comment: @Evgeny I have inserted the theorem I'm using into the OP